# Contador Crescente em uma Texbox

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou desenvolvendo um software que cada vez que o usuário clica no botão **salvar**, ele precisa adicionar o valor +1 em um `TextBox`.

Ex: Caixa = 1 -> **Salvar** -> Caixa = 2.

Toda vez que o usuário clica em **salvar**, ele mesmo tem que mudar o número da caixa, sempre adicionando 1. Tentei fazer um count no `TextBox` e converter o valor em `string` depois adicionar um count, mas não prestou.

Por que um `TextBox`? Porque meu usuário sempre vai precisar informar o valor inicial da ultima caixa que ele fechou.

Ex: O dia terminou na 32 Caixa, no dia seguinte ele precisa setar para o programa a caixa 33, a partir dai toda vez que ele começasse a clicar em **salvar**, ia adicionar 1.

```
private void textBox44_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int valor = Convert.ToInt32(textBox44);
    valor = valor++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você está tentando converter um `TextBox` pra inteiro e não o texto dele. Se você quer usar o texto, use a propriedade `Text`

```
int valor = Convert.ToInt32(textBox44.Text);
```